# Zipping the files

Tags: linux, command, zip

General Question . 
Example : 
In path: home/user/public_html/foldername 
foldername should be zipped .
 usually when we zip, zip file will be saved in the same path . Instead I want to zip to saved in some other path i.e  home/user
Just like Copy command target path and destination path

Is it possible  ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the first parameter, which is probably just your filename right now, can also be a absolute path.

```
zip foo foldername
```

vs

```
zip /home/user/foo foldername
```